# Android: Help creating an app for wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I want to create an android app where i can login and post something.  Am wondering if anyone know where i should start looking for solutions after here.

many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://android.wordpress.org/) you find an app for Android and Wordpress in the development area you can browse the source code, download sdks and all you need.

Or did you mean something else?